# How to buffer items up to a certain total size in Rx.NET?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Given:

1. `Observable<T> src`
2. `T` has an integer property `Size`
3. certain `SizeThreshold > 0`

Needed `Observable<List<T>>` where:

1. `list.Sum(o => o.Size)` >= `SizeThreshold`
2. `list.Take(list.Length - 1).Sum(o => o.Size)` < `SizeThreshold`

I.e. I need a variant on the `Buffer`.

My question - do I need to write it from scratch or does Rx.NET have anything that can be used sort of off-the-shelf?

Comment: If the sum is greater than `SizeThreshold`, do you keep removing items off the end of the list until it's small enough, and then these removed items get emitted in the next batch?

Comment: Never having used Rx.NET, but taking a quick look at the buffer source (https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Buffer.cs), it seems like you should be able to re-use a lot of it and just need to extend it rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: @moswald - no. The buffer is not changed once full. So, it may overflow the threshold, but only with the last item in it.

Comment: @mark, I know the question is already answered, but did you intend for the buffers to be discrete? Or overlapping?

Comment: Discrete. And the provided solution does indeed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Buffer` method has an overload for boundaries. You can create a boundary observable from yours initial observable by scaning it.

```
IObservable<Foo> src = Observable.Range(1, 200).Select(i => new Foo() {Size = i});
int sizeThreshold = 300;

var bufferBoundaries = src.Scan(0, (seed, val) =>
{
    if (seed >= sizeThreshold)
    {
        return val.Size;
    }
    return seed + val.Size;
}).Where(x => x >= sizeThreshold);

var result = src.Buffer(bufferBoundaries);
```

And the data class

```
class Foo
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Printing the result

```
result.Subscribe(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("New buffer. Count {0}. Sum {1}", x.Count, x.Sum(y => y.Size)));
    foreach (var foo in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Size);
    }
});
```

**Update**

This solution has one minor problem. The end of buffer is determined by bufferBoundaries or by src complete. Thus when the last element of the initial observable closes the buffer, you will get an empty list in result.

For example:

```
src = {3, 3}
sizeThreshold = 5;
```

result would be

```
{ [3, 3], [] }
```

**Update 2**

This solution works because the observables are somehow synchronized by rx.
If we add some async behavior, it breaks.
For example, if we change the result to

```
var result = src.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Buffer(bufferBoundaries);
```

or change the bufferBoundaries

```
var bufferBoundaries = src.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Scan...
```

Comment: I have tested this and it works +1. I am still trying to understand why it works. I subscribed to `bufferBoundaries` and it produces 300, 330, 316, 329.... How does `Buffer` use this information to group `Foo` objects together?, how does it know that it has to access the `Size` property? Can you please explain?

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. BTW, I do not see an empty buffer. I did the print out of the buffers and the last buffer contains 200. No empty buffer.

Comment: @YacoubMassad very good question indeed. `Buffer` remembers all the items from initial seqience and procude new `List` only when the second observable produce some value. `bufferBoundaries` can be changed to bufferBoundaries.Select(x => Unit.Default). But this works only because `src` and `bufferBoundaries` are synchronized by rx.

Comment: @mark i have updated my solution, please consider the problem it has.

Comment: Does not apply to me, so I am fine.

Comment: Thanks @DmitryDovgopoly. I think I understand it now. So it is all about when the value is generated and not what value is generated.

Comment: I do have a problem though. My observable gets subscribed twice - once by `Buffer` and once by `Scan`. My observable fetches the data from the database and being subscribed twice means it executes the fetching logic twice. So, I guess I need to make it hot? Not sure how to do it correctly, in a way that both `Scan` and `Buffer` get the same stream and remain synchronized.

Comment: Right now I call `Publish` before doing `Buffer` and `Scan` and then `Connect`. Seems to work.

Comment: I was about to suggest doing a `.Publish` to, but there is a more convenient overload that would work here that doesn't require a `.Connect()`. Do the `.Publish(published => { })` overload instead.